# How do I print all words begining with a specific letter in a text

Tags: awk, grep, terminal, find

How do I print all words begining with a specific letter in a text? and all words of 4 characters?

thanks

Comment: @OP Since this is your first post on this StackExchange, please show some effort in research (what have you tried so far?) or your post will be discarded as a student homework assignment (which your question appears to be by the way...). [Reading the help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help) will give you a better idea of how to get your questions answered.

Comment: ... I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to put all the words on their own line and then select the matching lines.

First, you would need to decide what constitutes a word. Is it any sequence of alphabetical character (with digits?), any sequence of non-spacing characters? Do you want to consider case?

Example:

```
tr -s '[:space:]' '[\n*]' < file | grep -i '^a'
```

Would report the sequences of non-whitespace that start with `a` case-insensitively.

Note that with GNU `tr`, it only works properly with single-byte characters.

For 4 character words, use `grep -xE '.{4}'`.